Why does executing a script containing SQL on PolarDB result in an error indicating inability to connect?
Why does executing a script containing SQL on PolarDB result in an error indicating inability to connect?
When executed individually, the SQL script runs without issues, and prior to execution, a retry detection method was reused to ensure connectivity to the database.

